Short story taking place after Internet encryption/anonymity is broken
This story is from Asimov's or F&SF I think from about 2010 (pre-pandemic anyway). It takes place after a breakthrough in computer science has broken most or all encryption on the Internet, leading to widespread turmoil as formerly anonymous posters of various things have been identified. The main character, an immigrant to the US is confronted by someone whom he gave apparently cruel advice, but it was due to poor understanding of English on part of the immigrant - what he meant was to give the advice "She's sick. Love her" to someone having personal relationship troubles, but what he wrote was "She's crazy. Fuck her."

This hypothetical is still very possible. Quanta Magazine did a special on it recently. "Cryptography's Mathematical 'Worlds': Which One Do We Live In?"

Decrypted by Eric Choi (2017), in Analog, not Asimov's or F&SF. This review confirms the significant details:

In a world where the development of quantum computers has led to the
decryption of everything on the internet, many changes have occurred.
One of them is that all internet trolls have been exposed. This has
consequences for Russian immigrant Mike Petrov, whose unfamiliarity
with English gets him in trouble.

